# Show Object data when hovering over image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple objects like below. I want to display for each item an Image specific to its type and when hovering over it, it should display its name and dmg for example. The hovering effect should be like it is in facebook when you mouseover a profile.

How do I do that and how do I save the object data in the image? Can I even do that with vanila javascript? If not what should I use these type of data binding?

```
let item = {
  name: "itemName",
  type: "weapon",
  dmg: 4
}
```

[**Inventory.js pastebin**](https://pastebin.com/LM1hRv35)

**index.html**

```
<div class="inventory" id="inventory">
    <div class="active-items" id="active-items">
      <h3 class="inventory-h3">Active Items</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="bag-items" id="bag-items">
      <h3 class="inventory-h3">Bag</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

EDIT:
When someone picks up an item the inventory ui is refreshed and an item is added but I want the item to contain the object data. I don't know how to accomplish this.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to SO! Do you have any of the html and css that you can include with your question? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img id="id" src="/src">
<div id="div_to_display_image_info"></div>


<script>
function(){
   let item = {
  name: "itemName",
  type: "weapon",
  dmg: 4
}
var img=document.getElementById('id')
 img.addEventListener('onmouseover', ()=>{
    document.getElementById("div_to_display_image_info").innerHTML = `dmg - ${item.dmg} name-${item.name}` 
})

}

</script>
```

Comment: maybe you would like to add design

Comment: you need to add your `let item` variable inside the function()

Comment: no you should not pass the item parameter because this function() is for automatically execute code it is similar to $(document).ready() in jquery  please see the edit

Comment: if you want to use Jquery this code works https://jsfiddle.net/c3emLyph/